# How to determine if sequence is within the list of ints?

Tags: python, list, sequence, traversal

I am having trouble when running a python program. The purpose is to determine whether the sequence `1, 2, 3` is within a given list of `int`s. When it runs two of the tests, the code works. However, the third test fails and I cannot figure out why.

My code is:

```
def has123(nums):
    s = ''.join(str(i) for i in sorted(nums))
    if '123' in s:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When passed through the argument `[1, 1, 2, 3, 1]` and `[1, 1, 2, 4, 1]`, it returns the correct output, but not for `[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Yes because when you sort the list your `[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]` becomes [`1,1,1,2,2,3`]. so there is no `123`

Comment: `for i in sorted(list(set(nums)))`

Comment: return '1,2,3' in ','.join((str(n) for n in nums))

Comment: @Adam Looks like you're able to find a counterexample for that yourself.

Comment: Define "is within".

Comment: if your `nums = [1, 2, 30]` then your algorithm will return `True`, which doesn't sound right

Comment: Why are you converting to a string and then comparing strings? That is completely wrong. Just check if each of the numbers 1,2,3 is in the list.

Comment: @zvone Because that can make it easier?

Comment: It does not make it easier. Your asking the question here is a proof of that ;) It is also not correct, not fast, not easy to maintain, not good for developing the correct developer mindset. Just do it right instead. MSH gave the correct solution in a comment - it is a one-liner.

Comment: @zvone MSH's "solution" incorrectly says `True` for `nums = [3, 1, 2]`. The question says "sequence". That means order matters. Which MSH's code (and apparently you) completely ignores. Whether the (fixed) string solution is correct depends on the number range. It might be. You don't know. It's also easy to maintain, and for longer sequences it can easily be faster than a similarly simple alternative, thanks to the advanced string search algorithm.

Comment: @KellyBundy But in the question, there is `sorted(nums)`, so the original order is obviously not relevant.

Comment: @zvone That's just their non-working attempt, you can't take that seriously. Or if you do, then explain why you don't take the `'123'` (which **is** ordered) equally seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `sorted()` from `s = ''.join(str(i) for i in sorted(nums))`

`sorted()` sorts the list and puts in ascending order

So in your case `[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]` is converted to `'111223'` when used `sorted()`, therefore not able to find the pattern

Comment: the ',' in the join is important, theres a difference between `1,2,3` and `12,3`

Answer (score 0):

In case you do need the sequence to be contiguous and in order (which is how I understand the wording), you can:

- iterate all the `1` in your list,
- for each `1`, check if it is the beginning of a `1,2,3`

```py
def has123(nums):
    all_1_idx = (i for i,n in enumerate(nums) if n==1)
    for i in all_1_idx:
        if nums[i:i+3] == [1,2,3]:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the sort was asked for or relevant.

Try this code:

```
def has123(nums: list) -> bool:
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
            return True

    return False
```

Here is what is happening:

- The target sequence is `[1,2,3]`, that's 3 elements.
- We calculate the length/size of the input list, let's use `[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]` as an example. The length is 6. We subtract 2 from it, I will explain why in a moment, and get 4.
- We then create a range like this `range(len([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]) - 2)`, this gives us a list or range like so: `[0,1,2,3]`.
- And now we iterate over this range ^^.  Looking up characters using these indices.
- The reason we subtracted 2 from `len(nums)` is to prevent an out of range error and so that we can check the last three elements of the list.

In a nutshell this code scoots over and checks character by character using the indices provided by the range function.